# Check shared drive is already mapped

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell for the first time to check if a unc path is already mapped, and if it is delete it to create it again under specific credentials.

The problem I have found is if the path exists in the net use list but has a drive letter, you have to delete it by the drive letter which can be of course random.  So I need to find out the drive letter when I match it but I am clueless as to how.

```
$userPass = '/user:Domain\User password';
$ltr = ls function:[d-z]: -n | ?{ !(test-path $_) } | random;
$share = '\\\\server\\folder';
$newMap = 'net use '+ $ltr + ' '$share + ' '$userPass;
foreach ($con in net use) {
    if ($con -match $share) {
        $MappedLetter = /*something here to find the matched drive?*/
        if ($MappedLetter) {
            net use $MappedLetter /delete
        } else {
            net use $share /delete
        }
    }
};

net use $newMap;
```

---

**[Edit]**

I have tried the `Get-PSDrive` but this only works IF the UNC path is mapped to a drive.  As these can at times be a "zombie", i.e. exist in `net use` but have no letter, this method won't always work.  I can combine the two methods (above an `Get-PSDrive`) but if anyone has a cleaner way please let me know!

Comment: I would suggest using `Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk` instead of `net use`. Then you will have drive and share information in one object.

Comment: Any chance you can expand on that for me please?  This is literally my first time using powershell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to check whether a particular share is already mapped via [`Get-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive?view=powershell-3.0):

```
$share = '\\server\share'

$drive = Get-PSDrive |
         Where-Object { $_.DisplayRoot -eq $share } |
         Select-Object -Expand Name

if ($drive) {
    "${share} is already mapped to ${drive}."
}
```

If you just want to remove the drive in case it is mapped you could do something like this:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {
    $_.DisplayRoot -eq $share
} | Remove-PSDrive
```

---

**Update:**

AFAIK PowerShell can't enumerate and remove disconnected drives directly. You can obtain that information from the registry:

```
$share = '\\server\share'
$drive = Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:Network\*' |
         Where-Object { $_.RemotePath -eq $share } |
         Select-Object -Expand PSChildName
```

or parse it out of the `net use` output:

```
net use | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '(?<=^Unavailable\s+)\w:'
} | ForEach-Object {
    $matches[0]
}
```

However, from what I know you still won't be able to remove the drive (e.g. via `net use`) as long as it remains disconnected. For removing a disconnected drive (e.g. when a share has become permanently unavailable) that you'd need to remove the mapping information from the registry:

```
$share = '\\server\share'
Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:Network\*' |
    Where-Object { $_.RemotePath -eq $share } |
    Remove-Item

# also remove mount point in Windows Explorer
$key = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2'
$subkey = Join-Path $key ($share -replace '\\', '#')
Get-ItemProperty "HKCU:${subkey}" | Remove-Item
```

Comment: `Root`is only the column header, use `DisplayRoot` for the real property name, it doesn't need to be enclosed in a {script block} `$drive = (Get-PSDrive | Where-Object DisplayRoot -eq $share).Name`

Comment: Thank you, if you want to put that as an answer I'll mark it up.  all working now

Comment: I've had mixed results un-mapping drives with the `Remove-PSDrive` cmdlet where I still need to `net use /DELETE` to get rid of zombie connections.

Comment: @RobboLew The enclosing in parenthese with ().Name is equivalent to Select. For the second script try `Get-PSDrive | ? DisplayRoot -eq $share | Remove-PSDrive`

Comment: Umm... yes. That's what you said your problem was. That you need to specify the assigned drive letter when trying to delete mapped drives via `net use`. So I thought it was safe to assume that there actually was an assigned drive letter.

Comment: Yeah I am with you now sorry! I didn't realise that only picks up ones with drive letters.  I have changed it so it does that first and then moves onto the code I posted which seems to be working!

Comment: Is there any option to find the drive letter of a disconnected drive dynamically?  This method works if the drive is mapped and active, however if the share is mapped to a drive but disconnected this doesn't pick it up and but you still need to delete the record by the drive letter and not the UNC path

Comment: @RobboLew See updated answer. If that still doesn't help: please update your question with sample `net use` output and indicate what you actually want to remove.

Comment: I believe it does everything I need to do perfectly now.  I'm just testing the code then was going to post it.  Many thanks!